# Dynamically override content-type response header in AWS CloudFront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, content-type, response-headers

I'm using AWS S3 and CloudFront to distribute content.

My files stored in S3 have `binary/octet-stream` type but in fact they can be images or documents.
When generating S3 URLs, I can override the response content type with a parameter like this: `https://my-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/foo/bar?[...]&response-content-type=image/jpeg`

Is there a way to do it with CloudFront (with the same S3 bucket as origin)?

I tried adding the same parameter -- it's ignored.
I can create a response headers policy and add a custom header overriding origin, but as far as I can see, it'll be the same for all files whereas I need to control it with a request parameter.